# Infinite loop LeetCode 153 Find Minimum in Rotated Sorted Array

Tags: algorithm, sorting, data-structures

I solved the leetcode problem and had added a line `if start == end return arr[start]` as an optimization. I am unable to come with a dataset where if I remove the line, why will the code go into an infinite loop. I have seen the leetcode submission fail if I remove the line. Here is my code. What data set can cause it to to into infinite recursion if I remove the first line inside the function?

```c
    public int findPivot(int[]arr, int start, int end) {
        if(start==end) return arr[start];
        if (arr[start]<arr[end]) return arr[start];
        if(end-start == 1) {
            return Math.min(arr[start],arr[end]);
        }
        
        
        int m = (start+end)/2;
        if( (m>0 && arr[start]<=arr[m-1]) && (arr[m]<=arr[arr.length-1]) ) {
            return arr[m];
        }
        if(m>0 && arr[start]<=arr[m-1]) {
            return findPivot(arr,m,end);
        } else {
            return findPivot(arr,start,m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if you get an array with one element and `start = end = 0`?

Comment: I had thought of it but did not even bother to dry run in my head. Feel really stupid, the condition speaks for itself. Thanks. That will cause an infinite loop. Although, I was also thinking can recursion eventually lead to one element array based on some data set that can cause it even if array was more than one element

Answer (score 0):

When resolving binary search questions, always test with two edge cases to avoid infinite loop, start = end and start + 1 = end.

Comment: I already have a similar check but my Q is around the different check that is in the first line of the function. I already have what you state
`
        if(end-start == 1) {
            return Math.min(arr[start],arr[end]);
        }
`